# Programmatically read fMP4 using ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mp4, libavcodec, libavformat

All of my attempts to parse fmp4 have failed with the following errors:

`avcodec_send_packet` returned with `-10949955291` and printed the following errors:

```
[h264 @ 0x105001600] No start code is found.
[h264 @ 0x105001600] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
```

**What did i do?**

Downloaded a perfectly playable `h.264` file and fragmented it using the following cmd

```
ffmpeg -i long.mp4 -an -sn -vcodec libx264 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*4)" -sc_threshold 0 -r 25 -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_list_size 99999 -start_number 1 -hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_fmp4_init_filename init.mp4 -t 30 -threads 0 big_bunny.m3u8
```

and used the following `AVIO` read example

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

std::vector<unsigned char> b1;
std::vector<unsigned char> b2;
bool initialized = false;
int bytesread = 0;

static int read_packet(void* opaque, uint8_t* buf, int buf_size)
{
    if (b1.size() && !initialized) {
        size_t bytesToRead = std::min(buf_size, (int)b1.size());
        ::memcpy(buf, b1.data(), bytesToRead);
        bytesread += bytesToRead;
        if (bytesread >= b1.size()) {
            initialized = true;
            bytesread = 0;
        }
        return bytesToRead;
    }

    ::memcpy(buf, b2.data() + bytesread, buf_size);
    bytesread += buf_size;
    return buf_size;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AVFormatContext* fmt_ctx = NULL;
    AVIOContext* avio_ctx = NULL;
    uint8_t *buffer = NULL, *buffer2 = nullptr, *avio_ctx_buffer = NULL;
    size_t buffer_size, buffer_size2, avio_ctx_buffer_size = 4096;
    char* input_filename = NULL;
    int ret = 0;
    struct buffer_data bd = {0};

    std::ifstream input1("/Users/x/Downloads/fmp4/init.mp4", std::ios::binary);
    std::ifstream input2("/Users/x/Downloads/fmp4/big_bunny1.m4s", std::ios::binary);

    b1 = std::vector<unsigned char>((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input1)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    b2 = std::vector<unsigned char>((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input2)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    avio_ctx_buffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(avio_ctx_buffer_size);

    fmt_ctx = avformat_alloc_context();
    avio_ctx = avio_alloc_context(avio_ctx_buffer, avio_ctx_buffer_size, 0, nullptr, &read_packet, NULL, NULL);
    fmt_ctx->pb = avio_ctx;

    AVDictionary* opts = NULL;
    //   av_dict_set(&opts, "movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov", 0);
    ret = avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, &opts);
    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(fmt_ctx, NULL);

    AVCodec* decoder = nullptr;

    decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(fmt_ctx->streams[0]->codecpar->codec_id);
    AVCodecContext* decoderCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);

    ret = avcodec_open2(decoderCtx, decoder, nullptr);

    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    while (true) {
        ret = av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt);

        ret = avcodec_send_packet(decoderCtx, &pkt);
        if (ret != 0)
            assert(false);

        for (;;) {
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(decoderCtx, frame);
            if (ret < 0) {
                break;
            }

            int g;
            g = 0;
        }
    }
```

I'm not even sure that this is the right way to process `fmp4` types. but for the clarity of this example, i simply loaded the init file into the first buffer, and the actual media file on the second buffer, and switch between the buffers respectfully to `buf_size`'s value.

Comment: 1.need use `avcodec_parameters_to_context` to copy codec parameters from input stream to output codec context. 2.sometime `avio_alloc_context` need custom `seek()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that in a case where you use `avio_alloc_context` demuxer get's all the needed info - see [Opening a media file](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavf__decoding.html), but this is a wild guess since your output shows no errors from the mp4 demuxer but only from the H.264 bitstream parser, so I am leaning that the probed file format could be raw H.264, but it is hard to tell. But if I am mistaken, you have not provided a seek callback, and demuxing an mp4 would certainly require seeking to jump around the boxes and then seek to the sample data. So, I'd first try to provide a seek callback, and see if that gets called. But from the example it is not sure why you even need the I/O callbacks, since the data reside in a file not in a memory location, so I'd suggest trying to use the standard [avformat_open_input](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga31d601155e9035d5b0e7efedc894ee49) way.